# How to align UILabel text to the vertical centre of box

Tags: ios, autolayout, alignment, uilabel, shrink

After using Auto shrink the text aligns itself to the top of the text box

```
 ____________
| AutoSized  |
|            |
|            |
 ____________
```

I need the text to align to the very centre like this

```
 ____________
|            |
| AutoSized  |
|            |
 ____________
```

How do I do this?

Lines is set to 0 otherwise the AutoShrink doesn't work well and cuts off the text. Baseline is set to align centres but the options don't change anything.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, set constraints by control-dragging from the label to the view behind it at an oblique angle and align it to both horizontal and vertical centers:

[image: Control-drag for constraint]

[image: Center on each axis]